# Qt drawImage is grainy when painter rotated

Tags: qt

I have a transparent PNG file that draws fine when you use a simple drawImage.

When I try to draw it rotated using the  `painter.rotate(...)` method, it draws a very grainy image.

Specifying `painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing)` does not help.

Is there a way to improve quality? By itself the image is fine.

Comment: wow! that one did the trick. Any don't you copy this comment to an answer so that I can credit you for the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the [`QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qpainter.html#RenderHint-enum) render hint:

> Indicates that the engine should use a smooth pixmap transformation algorithm (such as bilinear) rather than nearest neighbor.